# Javascript 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to make a loop in Javascript/jQuery. This block of code works fine on one run through (if I remove the 'for' loop), but if I put it in a loop it doesn't appear to work once and instead seems to hang.

```
var z=0;

for(z=0;z<=1000;z++){

$("#welcome").fadeTo(100,0.1,
    function(){$("#welcome").fadeTo(100,1.0,
        function(){$("#welcome").fadeTo(50,0.1,
            function(){$("#welcome").fadeTo(10,1.0,
                function(){$("#welcome").fadeTo(10,0.1,
                    function(){$("#welcome").fadeTo(10,1.0,
                        function(){$("#welcome").fadeTo(1,0.0,
                            function(){$("#welcome_distort").fadeTo(1,1.0,
                                function(){$("#welcome_distort").fadeTo(500,1.0,
                                    function(){$("#welcome_distort").fadeTo(1,0.0,
                                        function(){$("#welcome").fadeTo(1,1.0,
                                            function(){$("#welcome").fadeTo(50,0.1,
                                                function(){$("#welcome").fadeTo(50,1.0,
                                                    function(){$("#welcome").fadeTo(500,1.0
                                                    );}
                                                );}
                                            );}
                                        );}
                                    );}
                                );}
                            );}
                        );}
                    );}
                );}
            );}
        );}
    );}
);

}
```

Not the clearest explanation, I know, but any help (including advice with javascript loops) would be much appreciated.

Comment: what does this block of code do?  And once you put it in a for loops should the 'z' in the for loop play a role in the body of code?

Comment: @John i am not totally sure what you think you are doing here...

Comment: What are you trying to do? There must be an easier way than the nested nightmare you have here.

Comment: It just fades the selections in and out a few times. z plays no role in the code body.

Comment: Reselecting #welcome 11,000 times via jQuery and you wonder why it hangs....

Comment: haha - VERY new to this so not sure about alternative methods to anything! Thanks for the answers.

Comment: at the *very* least cache `$("#welcome")`, like `var $welcome = $("#welcome"); for(z=0...`

Comment: http://www.nooooooooooooooo.com/

Comment: If you're not using `z` in the body of your `for` loop, you'd be better off using a `while` loop with a simple integer comparison condition, and incrementing a counter variable after every iteration through the loop. However, doing what you're doing 1000 times is an incredibly bad idea (and, frankly, seems slightly useless).

Comment: What good does it do to do a `for` on the same selector?

Comment: Wrapped it up in a plugin for you: https://gist.github.com/1078676

Answer (score 11):

FYI, you can chain jQuery functions:

```
$('#welcome').fadeTo(100, .1).fadeTo(100, 1)...fadeTo(1, 0, function(){
    $('#welcome_distort').fadeTo(1, 1)...fadeTo(1, 0, function(){
        $('#welcome').fade...
```

The reason it doesn't work in a loop is because you're trying to do 1,000 animations at exactly the same time, thus -killing- the browser.  Wrap this in a function and re-call it when done:

```
function runAnimation(){
    $('#welcome')....function(){
        function(){
            function(){
               runAnimation();
            }
        }
    }
}
runAnimation();
```

Comment: i would upvote this if only it was a comment. There's no reason to post this as an answer when it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: In my opinion, there isn't any real question other than "why does my browser hang", for which this is a very clear explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the [easing](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html) plugin? I can only assume you are attempting to do some sort of custom animation with this craziness.

Otherwise, I would create an array of all the variables you need to fade to. And cache the `$("#welcome")` call, and possibly use [deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Comment: Agreed, in all seriousness tell us more about what you can accomplish and we can suggested better alternatives like easing.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the loop will iterate instantly and not wait for your callbacks.

Try this:

```
var counter = 0;

function do_huge_nested_craziness(){
    if(counter > 100)
    {
        return false;
    }
    /// do huge nested craziness..

    /* in the last callback add this:
    counter++;
    do_huge_nested_craziness(); //recursion
    */
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `1000` is intended to be "run forever" (considering it'll be about 90 minutes of animation), thus no need for the counter.

Comment: I'm sure you're right - just keeping it as close to the OP's request as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, try this instead of the monstrosity you have =P.

```
function make_fader(vals) {
    var next_func = animate_me;
    if (vals.length > 1) {
        var next_vals = [];
        for (var i=1; i<vals.length; i++) next_vals[i-1] = vals[i];
        var next_func = make_fader(next_vals);
    }

    return function() { $("#welcome").fadeTo(vals[0][0], vals[0][1], next_func); };
}
var fader_func = make_fader([[100, 0.1], [100,1.0],[50,0.1],[10,1.0]...]);

var g_count = 0;
function animate_me() {
    g_count += 1;
    if (g_count < 1000) 
        fader_func();            
}
```